# How to stop the memory leak in "com.newrelic.agent.Transaction"

Tags: memory-leaks, jvm, newrelic

I have integrated newRelic-api to my service, just for monitoring. But in the past few days the service has been going down because of OOM. I read a post in newRelic's forum's which basically says that its a problem with my service and asks to increase the -xmx. Mine is a tiny service which doesn't need much memory. So I have put -xmx to 3GB - https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/relic-solution-troubleshooting-java-agent-memory-leaks-and-outofmemoryerror-issues-with-eclipse-memory-analyzer-tool/59596

Below I have added the dependency in the service and all I do is add newRelic.jar to the JavaOptions in my DockerFile `-javaagent:tmp/newrelic/newrelic.jar`

There are multiple questions here, since this is a tool which is good to have, but not critical for me, I can't spend much time debugging the issue, so if this is a known issue please let me know if there is any configuration that I can add or remove from `newrelic.yml`. I am currently using default settings `common: &default_settings` in it.

Should I downgrade newRelic since I am not using any of their advanced features? Or should I upgrade to the latest newRelic versions?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>newrelic-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is what Eclipse MAT shows [image]

Comment: If you remove the new relic agent, does the service still go down with an OOM eventually?

Comment: @AlBlue Yes, it did go down eventually today after I removed NewRelic